# How to open Power Options > System Settings with cmd / Powershell, or other

Tags: powershell, cmd, powercfg

After looking over the Internet for days now, I have no other choices that ask you my question.

How can I open, with cmd / run / powershell (or whatever) the followong control panel:

[Choose what closing the lid does](http://postimg.org/image/xpfjhehdn/)

I know how to enter powercfg.cpl but I'm stuck opening it to get there:

[Lid Options](http://postimg.org/image/4h2ht6whh/)

I also know this is possible to change power plans with cmd but this is not how I must do that.

Many thanks in advance and have a great day :D

Comment: This question is On Topic because it is about using PowerShell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%windir%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.PowerOptions /page  pageGlobalSettings
```

See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330741.aspx) for Canonical Names of Control Panel Items

Comment: Super super Thanks for this! I'm so relief now, wow :)

Comment: Note: %windir% didn't work for me, but c:\Windows did. (Context inside a .Net application: Process.Start("c:\Windows\System32\control.", "/name Microsoft.PowerOptions")

Answer (score -1):

Find registry, that hanles this and modify/distribute it with powershell.

Comment: This provides no help at all